# Portable open source C++ compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, portability

What is a portable open source standard C++ compliant compiler that can be ported to an i386 OS?

Gcc and llvm are both written in C++.  I've found a few portable C compilers but not a C++ one.

**edit**
 while cross-compilation would be obviously an option to get a C++ compiler working on the target OS, I'm looking for a compiler "designed" to be portable, if exists. Something like Comeau's one, but open source.

Comment: You normally bootstrap a compiler by crosscompiling. You don't need a compiler *running* on the target OS, you just need one which can *generate* for it. This means the language in which the compiler's implemented is largely irrelevant. If you have a C compiler on that OS, can't you integrate its backend into GCC or Clang to get them to cross-compile for it?

Comment: Older versions of GCC are written in C, so you can build one of those, and then use it to build a newer version of GCC (which will support the latest standards).

Comment: Both GCC & Clang/LLVM can be *cross-compilers*

Comment: So you are not interested in portable compilers, but in bootstrapping principles? Note that such a bootstrap option won't necessarily making a port to a new target easier. It is more a way that people can duplicate making an initial binary on a /supported/ target. (like e.g. debian requires)

Answer (score 4):

If you have an assembler in that OS, you can generate assembler files from the gcc sources with -S and then link in your target OS. Is a hard work, but is not impossible.